# dotnet --version can't find GLIBCXX_3.4.21

Tags: centos7, .net-core

I installed `.donet core` and `code` under `CentOS 7` but I get this error:

```
curl -sSL -o dotnet.tar.gz https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkID=816869
sudo mkdir -p /opt/dotnet && sudo tar xvf dotnet.tar.gz -C /opt/dotnet
sudo ln -s /opt/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin
curl -sSL -o code.el7.x86_64.rpm https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkID=760867

sudo yum localinstall code.el7.x86_64.rpm 


dotnet --version

dotnet: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by dotnet)
```

Comment: As per https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxcentos - did you install pre requisites: `sudo yum install libunwind libicu`?

Comment: Yes those are installed.